# Rails: Precompiled assets missing node modules

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, node-modules, yarnpkg

I am using yarn with my rails 5.1 app (not webpacker, just the default asset pipeline).

Running a local server in development environment, I experience no issues with my assets.

But as soon as I precompile my assets (the environment doesn't matter) or let Heroku package my assets, all stylesheets (of node modules) I imported from within my `application.sass` file don't work anymore.

The reason for that behavior is that sass compiles all files into one output file, but because of some reason appears to miss the `@import` statements which include node modules and load these files separately.

So this:

```
@import "components/index.sass"
@import "nodemodule/nodemodule.css"
```

Compiles to this in development:

```
// content of "components/index.sass"
// content of "nodemodule/nodemodule.css"
```

and to this in production:

```
// content of "components/index.sass"
@import "nodemodule/nodemodule.css"
```

while loading `node_module/nodemodule.css` separately as an asset, but the browser cannot resolve it. Javascript works fine.

Comment: thanks for the bounty .. do you need any help?

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I haven't found the time to test this yet, because I am currently occupied by another project. Bounty almost expired, so I assigned it to the answer appearing to be the most helpful. Hopefully I am able look into the problem this weekend.

Comment: ok. let me know when you need help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found the problem. It is a very nasty bug of the `sass-rails` gem & an unfortunate design of the `sprockets` component of Rails.

#### 1) `sass-rails`

`@import` does not seem to work with `node_modules` as it does with other assets. While those other assets get compiled into one file, `node_modules` only get referenced, loaded by the browser as separate sources, but ultimately not being used by the browser.

#### 2) `sprockets`

Sprockets' `require` statement does only work if it is at the beginning of a file. Or as they put it in their [documentation](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#directives):

> Note: Directives are only processed if they come before any application code. Once you have a line that does not include a comment or whitespace then Sprockets will stop looking for directives. If you use a directive outside of the "header" of the document it will not do anything, and won't raise any errors.

However, in my case, I was importing directives from a file that itself was imported from `application.sass`.

Answer (score 10):

The links are from my project that you can use as reference
in your [`asset.rb`](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfbackend/blob/public/config/initializers/assets.rb) you need to include the `/node_modules` path in your default load_path.

If you open the `rails console` and input `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` you should see the new path `/yourproject/node_modules` added.

Then you simply write:

```
@import "nodemodule.css"
```

In my case for bootstrap 4 in my [`application.scss`](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfbackend/blob/public/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss)

```
@import bootstrap/scss/bootstrap
```

which correspond to the file in `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss`

[image]

for `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` you can check my [`application.js`](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/surfbackend/blob/public/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem. Inspired by [this comment](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/417#issuecomment-401439001) removing file extensions from the imports ended up fixing it.

This didn't work:

```
@import "@shopify/polaris/styles.css";
@import "@uppy/core/dist/style.css";
@import "@uppy/dashboard/dist/style.css";
```

while this did:

```
@import "@shopify/polaris/styles";
@import "@uppy/core/dist/style";
@import "@uppy/dashboard/dist/style";
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day

Comment: For some reason, this worked locally, but didn't work after deploying to Heroku. This solution fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

The node_modules need to be installed with `npm install` for example, so they're probably not getting installed on Heroku. Check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Most likely, you need to setup a Node.js buildpack which will install your npm dependencies.

Comment: I have added the Node.js buildpack. The heroku logs say, that node_modules are being installed.

Comment: Just curious, in your snippets you have the folder name as ‘node_module’ instead of ‘node_modules’. Is that a typo?

Comment: `yarn` replaces `npm`

Comment: @JeffF. In my actual code, I omitted `node_modules/` completely. As far as I understand I should be able to reference the subfolders of `node_modules` directly, if it is in my asset paths.