# Using javascript plugins in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use Uppy plugin, a plugin for uploading images, in a Ruby on Rails application.

The basic functionality works through CDN bundles, and I have no problem with that, this works fine. My problem happens when I need to use additional plugins by Uppy.

Importing those is done through using, require. For example:

```
const AwsS3 = require('@uppy/aws-s3')
const ms = require('ms')
```

How can I include those in a Rails project?

Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602764/how-to-use-npm-packages-in-rails) question suggest using `npm init` in a rails project, but this seems very radical. Is there an easier way to include a javascript library such as the one mentioned in a Rails project?

Comment: Are you using the older assets pipeline (js files are in `app/assets/javascripts`) or the newer rails-6 webpack pipeline (files in `app/javascript/packs`)?

Comment: the older one app/assets/javascripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mimic the behaviour of the CDN, you can add javascript files to a `vendor/assets/javascripts` folder. You can then require the files manually in application.js:

```
//= require uppy-1.2.3.min.js
//= require uppy-aws.js
//= require uppy-stuff.js
```

This avoids NPM entirely.

If you want to manage things via NPM, you would want to:

1. run `npm init` in the root of the project
2. add node_modules to your .git_ignore
3. run `npm install --save PACKAGE_NAME` for all of your needed packages
4. add `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')` to your application config, most likely in `app/config/initializers/assets.rb`
5. add the full path of required packages to application.js,ie `//= require @uppy/core/src/index.js`

This only work if the packages have a pre-built version packaged with the release. This is typically in a dist folder instead of a src folder

Comment: Ok, so excuse the question if it sound stupid, but I know next to nothing about javascript.
So the first option, would entall downloading the files, adding them to my folders manually and then including them in the asset pipeline?

Comment: That is correct. For Uppy specifically you can download the full package here: https://transloadit.edgly.net/releases/uppy/v1.3.0/uppy.min.js. If you put that in `vendor/assets/javascipts/uppy.js` you can add it to `application.js` with `//= require uppy.js`. There are downsides to this such as larger file sizes that you can solve with more complex solutions like webpacker, but this will get you started.

Comment: Also, setting up a full featured, "modern" javascript environment can be very complicated. It absolutely does not sound stupid to have questions about how to go about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan, but one more question if I may. Any ideas if this link that you gave here has uppy-aws, and if not where can I download it separately?
And thanks a lot again for the answer, ill try it and tell you :)

Comment: It is included. You can access it via `Uppy.AwsS3`

Comment: Ok when I try to use smt such as const AwsS3 = require('@uppy/aws-s3') I'm getting an error require not defined. Is there any alternative to this? 
I mean I'm using require in application.js well and good, but how can I set the variable AwsS3

Comment: In your assets/javascript/application.js file, doing `//= require 'whatever'` is essentially copy/pasting the file inline. This is effectively the same as using a CDN, at which point you can access it via `Uppy.AwsS3`, just with the benefits of keeping your code under your control

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan! :)